# Html local file is not displayed when I decrease to sw600dp in Android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I display a local html file in a webview on a 10'' tablet and a sw720dp density when I change layout for a 7'' tablet and a sw600dp nothing appears, it looks like as if the screen it too small? I dont get an error in LogCat

I load the html file with

```
htmlwebview.reload();
htmlwebview.loadUrl(uri3.toString());
```

Is there something like fitXY for the webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set property measureWithLargestChild of the Parent Layout I think it should do the work